# MOG2 background substraction : Probability Density Function

Tags: opencv, mog

Please, anybody can explain to me why on OpenCV MOG2 function for background substraction i can't found the implementation of Probability Density Function ?

There is any trick on the proposed implementation ?

Comment: Please provide more details about your question so we can better assist you. Check out this guide on how to post good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Here is the paper : [Improved Adaptive Gaussian Mixture Model for Background Subtraction](http://www.zoranz.net/Publications/zivkovic2004ICPR.pdf)

Class reference : [cv::BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 Class](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d7/d7b/classcv_1_1BackgroundSubtractorMOG2.html)

Implementation : [bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/video/src/bgfg_gaussmix2.cpp)

The trick as mentioned in the implementation: "Number of Gaussian components is adapted per pixel."